# Увеличить картинку при клике

Tags: javascript, css3

```
$(function () {
  $('.image').click(function (event) {
    var i_path = $(this).attr('src');
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div><div id="magnify"><img src="' + i_path + '"><div id="close-popup"><i></i></div></div>');
    $('#magnify').css({
      left: ($(document).width() - $('#magnify').outerWidth()) / 2,
      // top: ($(document).height() - $('#magnify').outerHeight())/2 upd: 24.10.2016
      top: ($(window).height() - $('#magnify').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
    $('#overlay, #magnify').fadeIn('fast');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '#close-popup, #overlay', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#overlay, #magnify').fadeOut('fast', function () {
      $('#close-popup, #magnify, #overlay').remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: какую ошибки в консоли пишет? или что именно происходит?

Comment: что не получается? почему не сделаете код воспроизводимым? как должно быть? что сейчас не так?

Comment: дальше ничего не происходит @ThisMan только возникает рамка которая задана в css

Comment: должно появляться новое окно на этой же  странице и в ней 100% картинки

Comment: а получается на самой странице уменьшенная копия картинки,это то я поняла что в стилях задаешь ширину,а так чтобы вощникало окно. я вставила код js в html файл с тегом scipt и прописала в стилях

Comment: @kizoso https://codepen.io/delya_mi/pen/MqYWoz